# SSIS: Get Date for Day of the Week

Tags: ssis, date, ssis-expressions

In SSIS, how do I get the date for a specific day of the week? For example, how do I get last Sunday's date?

I assume I have to do some subtraction on the day-of-week, but not sure:

```
DATEADD("d", -DATEPART("DW", GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the date for any given day in the current week:

```
DECLARE @DesiredDay INT = 0;
DECLARE @OutputDate DATE;
SET DATEFIRST 1; /* Monday is day 1 */
SET @OutputDate = DATEADD(d, @DesiredDay - DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), GETDATE());
SELECT @OutputDate;
```

I'm setting `@DesiredDay` to `0` since you requested Sunday in your question.  For Monday, set this to 1, for Tuesday set it to 2, etc.

Comment: I'm after the SSIS expression please Max.

Comment: In SSIS, you could obtain the date for Sunday using : DATEADD("d", 0 - DATEPART("dw", GETDATE()), GETDATE())

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking - adjust the "0" value the day-of-the-week you require.